# Jenkins - Throttle Concurrent Build Plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

We are using the [Throttle Concurrent Build Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/throttle-concurrents/) version 2.0.3 for our Jenkins declarative pipelines.

Our Jenkins is running on AWS EC2 instance and is running all the jobs on the same instance. We have configured 10 executors in Jenkins system configuration.

Some of our jobs are configured to run every minute and perform state machine like activity for a subset of records on the database. We have recently started noticing - although the job is setup to run only 1 build concurrently as show in screenshot below, some times there is more than one instances of the same job executing and NOT queued up.

[image: Jenkins jobs throttle build plugin configuration]

I remember there was a time if the on-going job runs for more time than the next scheduled build, any new job runs would be queued as shown in the screenshot below

[image: Jenkins jobs obeying throttle build plugin config]

But, not anymore. Occasionally,  we have started noticing that the jobs are behaving as if the Throttle Concurrent Builds plugin is not even configured.

Any suggestions on where / how to start debugging or what to fix?

NOTE: I tried googling and finding any open suggestions or help regarding this but there is no recent issues reported about this plugin. So, trying to figure out how I even start about this issue. I am not a Jenkins expert by any standard. Hence, any direction / guidance would help. Thank you.